# Хранение пути файла в БД

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

В базе SQL Server храниться путь к файлу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Тип поля `path` в БД `nvarchar(MAX)`.
При получение объекта (с помощью Entities Framework) с данным полем

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

, как видите получаю строку с **удвоенными слешами**.

Попытки использования Replace в различных комбинациях не помогли мне.

Как правильно загрузить путь файла из БД? Или может быть я не правильно вообще храню путь в БД?

Comment: Это - совершенно правильное представление строки в виде строкового литерала в C#. В самой строке все правильно - это отладчик так показывает.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Работать должно и без этого, но если нужно то можно сделать так :

**Вариант 1:**

```
 var result = report.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

**Вариант 2:**

```
var result = Regex.Unescape(report);
```

Answer (score 5):

Путь файла загрузился у вас правильно, просто слеши у вас заэкранировались. Почитайте [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/en-en/library/ms228362.aspx) о строках и escape-символах.